# Keep the latest date for ID with multiple readings

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet with data formatted like:

```
DATE        ID       Notes               Year
8/30/2014   2969513  sdsdfsdfsdfsd       2011
8/30/2014   2969513  sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf     2011
8/30/2014   2969513  werwerwerwer        2011 
4/20/2016   2969513  fgsfgnghghfm        2015
4/20/2016   2969513  fgdjgmcvbnjh,       2015 
4/20/2016   2969513  jkhmfdcghnsf 
12/3/2013   2951257  ouiutyrrdgbb
12/3/2013   2951257  sjysghjgc,cg
12/3/2013   2951257  fnjsdxtgdkmdx
12/3/2013   2951257  rsedgsfyki.,j
9/12/2014   2951257  trhtyrkjutdjk
9/12/2014   2951257  ethysryjtyjyj
9/12/2014   2951257  trhsryjdyjydj
9/12/2014   2951257  trhsdryjdtyjh
```

With thousands of ID's. I need to clean the data so that only the latest readings per ID is displayed. The end result would be something like:

```
DATE        ID       Notes            Year
4/20/2016   2969513  fgsfgnghghfm     2015
4/20/2016   2969513  fgdjgmcvbnjh,    2015
4/20/2016   2969513  jkhmfdcghnsf     2015
9/12/2014   2951257  trhtyrkjutdjk
9/12/2014   2951257  ethysryjtyjyj
9/12/2014   2951257  trhsryjdyjydj
9/12/2014   2951257  trhsdryjdtyjh
```

Edit: I have tried sorting the data by Date and ID, and then filtering unique ID's. This left me with the latest dates and their associated ID's but I didn't retain the multiple readings rows. I can attempt this in SQL, I'm currently attempting to create a table and run orderby on it.

Comment: _3.  Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it._ -[Help Center: What's On Topic Here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: There are two formula methods: 1 Helper columns, where we put a helper column that puts an ever increasing number by the ones that should be returned,  This requires that the data be sorted first on the ID then on the date.  2. array formulas.  With thousands of line I would steer away from array formulas.  I would use vba in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

If I assume your data is in columns A to D then your column to say whether you can use it or not is:

```
=$A2=MAX(IF($B$2:$B$15=$B2,$A$2:$A$15,0))
```

Make sure you do it as an array formula: ctrl + shift + enter

Alternatively don't do it in Excel, use a database and you'll be much better off.

Comment: Thanks for your input! But this just gives me True and False values?

Comment: Then just filter for the True ones